# IntelliJ version 12.2 reformat on file save

Tags: intellij-idea

How to set reformat and remove unused imports upon file save( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) in IntelliJ version 12.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working in IntelliJ IDEA, files are always saved automatically by the IDE. Because of that, there is no need to ever press Ctrl-S, and therefore IntelliJ IDEA does not provide a way to execute actions when files are saved.

Unused imports can be removed automatically directly as files are being edited: Settings | Editor | Auto Import | Optimize imports on the fly

Reformatting code automatically can be performed before a VCS commit; there's a corresponding checkbox in the Commit Changes dialog.